# Strange div stacking behavior

Tags: html, css

Apologies for the bad HTML here, I'm not very good at it. When trying to make a HTML page for a friend's Discord bot, something weird started happening when trying to get the background div (class of `background`) behind the `body`. Simple enough, I just set a z-index of -1. This causes issues with the Discord bot listing website, though, as it sends that background behind *everything* and means that it's hidden. "No problem, I'll just set the z-indexes to be 765 and 766 right?" Wrong. I've tried it on the Discord bot website and codepen.io, any time I use a non-negative index on `main` it brings it to the front. I could make the indexes for `background` and `body` 0 and 999, `background` will still be in front. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Relevant CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.background {
  background: url(URL);
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<body>
*things*
</body>

<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: You've put a div after the body, did you mean to do this? All the content you want shown on the page should be inside the `body` tag, even backgrounds. Here are the rules: put everything inside the body tag, but put `link` tags, `meta` tags, `title` tags and occasionally `script` and `style` tags go in your `head`, but everything else goes in your body. If you want special tags to put elements in, I'd reccomend searching up "semantic html", this will show you a lot of tags to put navigation, content, and sidebars in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
body {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/1000);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I think there might be some confusion with how the elements work. I think you're making it a step more complicated. Is that so?

Comment: Yep. That works fine on the codepen, not sure why I ever made it so complicated. The bot listing website is still acting up, though.

Comment: Well, if you think of HTML as just boxes - that will help. "Stacking" on top of each other with positioning is very rare. : )